# jQuery getScript errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.10.2 and I'm getting the following error regarding the use of getScript. I load jquery, then call a JS file that contains this code. I even use an alert with the version of jQuery right before getScript is called so that I know it is loaded.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getScript' of undefined
```

Here is the code

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {   
    load_scripts();
});

function pause_for_jquery(){
    setTimeout(load_scripts, 50);
}


function load_scripts(){
    if (!window.jQuery) {
        pause_for_jquery();
    }
    else{
        alert(jQuery.fn.jquery); //this alert works and displays '1.10.2'
        $.getScript("url here", function() {});
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why do you wonder that `$` is undefined if you have used `$.noConflict()`?

Comment: @Bergi: I think implied in this question is that the OP doesn't really understand what `$.noConflict()` really does, or why it's used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$.noConflict();` deregisters the `$` object. You will need to use the longer `jQuery()` form:

```
jQuery.getScript("url here", function() {});
```